# Pass arguments by reference to fmt

Tags: go

How do I print in go without passing arguments by value (copies) to fmt?

Perhaps something like this (hypothetical * flag)?

```
fmt.Printf( "Value of pointer %*s", &mystruct.somelargestring )
```

Currently:

```
fmt.Printf( "val is %v, %v\n", &mystruct.val, mystruct.Val )
val is 0xf84061d170, somestring
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your reason for asking is that you are concerned about memory and performance issues when printing a large string, since you believe that a copy will be made and passed into the fmt.Printf function.

You do not have to worry about that in this case, because a copy of the byte array holding your string data is not what gets passed into the function.

In Go, a string is a read-only byte slice, so what gets passed into the function is just that - a read-only byte slice.

A slice in go is a value that holds a reference to an element of an array (the element at slice[0]), amongst other things, like the length of the slice and its capacity (see links below for a more in-depth explanation of slices).

It is important to understand that a slice does not hold the data (actual bytes of your string) - it only holds a reference to that data.

In the case of a string, the slice is read-only and you don't have direct access to the underlying array.

So, since your string variable holds a slice and not the underlying array and a slice is only a reference to that array, when you call the fmt.Printf function, you are passing a reference.

Everything in Go gets passed by value, sure, but since what you are passing is a value that contains a reference to you array, a copy of the underlying array won't get made; only a copy of the value holding the reference to the underlying array gets made, which is cheap, so you can use:

```
fmt.Printf( "%s", mystruct.somelargestring )
```

without any copies of your large string being made.

To clarify the above, it would be helpful for you to read:

http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

and

http://blog.golang.org/slices

The Go Language Specification would also help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a pointer, `fmt.Printf` will use a copy of the pointer (a copy of the "pointer value"), not a copy of the object itself.
See [Calls](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls):

> In a function call, the function value and arguments are evaluated in the usual order.
>   After they are evaluated, the parameters of the call are passed **by value** to the function and the called function begins execution.

I usually use:

```
myobject *MyObject
fmt.Printf("%v", myObject)
```

Comment: I am asking some simple questions that should have quick answers like yours, but SO won't let me accept until a few minutes have passed.

Comment: @erjoalgo no problem. The idea is: if you are using pointers, there won't be any *large* copy.

Comment: Using %v on an address prints the object's address:
fmt.Printf( "A: %v, B: %v\n", &mystruct.A, &mystruct.B )
A: 0xf840704098, B: 0xf8407040a8

Comment: @erjoalgo I use `mystruct.A` directly, not `&mystruct.A`. As long `A` is a pointer, the copy won't be large. See for instance http://play.golang.org/p/2qrCLc-bWD

Comment: @erjoalgo I confirm that if A is a string, then a copy will be done (or the pointer is printed if you are using `&`).

Comment: @erjoalgo then it is a copy: everything is passed by value.

Comment: fmt could easily add a format flag to specify whether to attempt to dereference an argument. I was asking whether this was implemented already.

Comment: @erjoalgo not that I know of.